# Async/await is blocking? if not why its result is different from promises?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I do some research about async/await but I am confuse. It says that async/await is non-blocking. I look into developer.mozilla.org async function example.
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');

  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);

  //uncomment this code to see promise result
  //resolveAfter2Seconds().then(result=>{
  //console.log(result);
  //});

  console.log('calling end');
}

asyncCall();
```

async/await result is

```
> "calling"
> "resolved"
> "calling end"
```

but promise result is

```
> "calling"
> "calling end"
> "resolved"
```

so if async/await is non-blocking then why it does not console "calling end" before the "resolved" ??

Comment: `await` is not blocking. It allows to write async code like sync code and execute the lines in the order they are written, while being non-blocking (timeouts, interval, HTTP requests etc still run concurrently). `.then()` does not do that at all. What's inside `.then()` isn't execued as it is written, it's executed later. Your example is flawed, the two codes are not equivalent, that's why you are getting two different results.

Comment: @zhulien may you provide me some blog or documentation reference where I will studied about it in more details?

Answer (score 4):

Your Promise code isn't the same as the async variant.

```js
async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  
  console.log('calling end');
}
```

Would be the same as

```
function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');

  resolveAfter2Seconds()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);

      console.log('calling end');
    });
}
```

Comment: There won't be 2 `.then`'s, only a single one as there are no more `await`s involved.

Comment: True, I just extended his example which already had the first `then()` but I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

as @zhulien mentioned, The `await` keyword is the magic.

To understand it better execute the following code:

with `await`

```
asyncCall();
console.log("this log you will see right after 'calling' log");
```

without `await` (just remove `await` in asyncCall - hey you know that's fine to use async without await, but not vice versa).

```
asyncCall();
console.log("this log you will see right after 'calling end' log");
```

so in the same closure, anything after the `await` will be blocked, where as in code flow continues from calling function and that's what the doc meant as non-blocking :)